# Making my answer more visible

Tags: support, answers

I have seen an [old question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22806/how-to-move-faster-in-terraria/) on a game that has evolved a lot.
Seeing that all the answers were based on **older versions** of the game, I put an answer that adds a lot, based on the components in the **newests versions**.

However, I don't think my answer will be visible enough, due to its fresh state.

So, my question is : **Is there a way to promote any answer somewhere on my profile, in order to increase its visibility ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you just added an answer, that will bump it back to the front page.

There's no real way to add a question/answer to your profile, unless you link it in your About Me section where you can put whatever text you like (so you could include a link there if you wanted),  although that doesn't guarantee more visibility (as people have to visit your profile specifically to see it).  Unfortunately, there is no other way to add questions to your profile in the way you like (although your profile does list all of your questions and answers anyhow, you can't highlight specific ones short of using your About Me box.)

You could also add a bounty to the question, although since you answered the question, you would have to have the bounty set at a minimum of 100 reputation, which you don't have yet (and if you set a bounty, you lose that amount of rep until you earn it again through up votes etc). One of the bounty reasons is to draw more attention to a question, which would then also draw attention to your answer.

Comment: The small thing is that the 'About me' is the same all over the StackExchange accounts, as far as I saw. Oh well, I'll stop being impatient.

Comment: @Anton Your "About me" is site-specific.

Comment: @john it can be (but when you edit, you also get the option to push to all sites).